# Xamarin.Forms Consume API

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Can someone help me?

I'm try to consume api in my apps (I'm still learning). I can successfully call the api and get the data, but debug ended in DeserializeObject.

Can someone help me, and tell what must I do? or reference how to fix this?

This is my code:

**My ViewModels**

from ViewModels I call `GetHeroes()`, which calls my class in services.

```
    public class DotaViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public DotaViewModel()
    {
        GetHeroes(); // Start From Here
    }

    IDotaApi _rest = DependencyService.Get<IDotaApi>();

    private ObservableCollection<Hero> heroes;

    public ObservableCollection<Hero> Heroes
    {
        get { return heroes; }
        set
        {
            heroes = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Heroes"));
        }
    }

    public async void GetHeroes()
    {
        var result = await _rest.getheroes(); // Go Inside Here

        if (result != null)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**My Services**

I got the data and stored it to `var result`, but my debug just when I `DeserializeObject`.

```
public class DotaApi : IDotaApi
{
    string Base_url = "https://api.opendota.com/api/heroes";
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Hero>> getheroes()
    {

        string url = Base_url;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);

        if (responseMessage.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var result = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // I Got Data Here

            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Hero>>(result); // But Stuck Here

            return json;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**This is My Model**

```
public class Hero
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string localized_name { get; set; }
    public string primary_attr { get; set; }
    public string attack_type { get; set; }
    public List<string> roles { get; set; }
    public int legs { get; set; }

    //[
      //{"id":1,
       //"name":"npc_dota_hero_antimage",
       //"localized_name":"Anti-Mage",
       //"primary_attr":"agi",
       //"attack_type":"Melee",
       //"roles":["Carry","Escape","Nuker"],
       //"legs":2}
      //}
   //]


}
```

Comment: what does your json look like?  Does it match your model?

Comment: i think it is match, i use json to c# to create my Hero class

Comment: Your comment says your code gets stuck. Does it just not continue, or do you actually get an exception? Why are you deserializing to `ObservableCollection` doesn't seem like there is anything to observe.

Comment: Try using a List instead.  And please post a sample of your json

Comment: @Cheesebaron i think it not continue, the next button is disabled

Comment: @Jason : ok sir, i already add json example, i write it in my model as a comment,

Comment: did you try changing ObservalCollection to LIst?  Have you wrapped the code in a try/catch?

Comment: ah ok, i will try it sir, thx for advice

Comment: @Dwiansyah Hi, if you have solved it, remember to update the solution as an answer, that will be helpful for others who have the same problem.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT ok, i will update the answer asap when i solved it sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks For all,

I finally solved the problem,

this is purely my fault cause I didn't really understand how it worked before,
so i try to understand more deeply about ObservableCollection and how to debug

now i know, there is nothing wrong with DeserializeObject like i said in my question (sorry for that), the problem is in GetHeroes() function

```
public async void GetHeroes()
    {
        var result = await _rest.getheroes();

        if (result != null)
        {
            Heroes = result; // i missed this code, so. I haven't entered my data before
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the API calling method like below and add a debug point to the exception and check the issue

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<Hero>> getheroes()
{
    string Base_url = "https://api.opendota.com/api/heroes";

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var data = new ObservableCollection<Hero>();
        try
        {
            var content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(Base_url);
            var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Hero>>(response);

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode && result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return data;
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok sir, thx for your answer, i will try it first